# send JSONObject with POST Request url-encoded with retrofit

Tags: android, post, http-post, retrofit2, url-parameters

I'm using the code below to send parameters inside a JSONObject:

`APIClient class`

```
@NonNull
public Retrofit getDefaultClient() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cookieJar(ApiClientCookieJar.getInstance())
            .connectTimeout(Info.connectTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(Info.readTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(Info.writeTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(chain -> {
                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", " application/json")
                        .build();
                if (AppData.getInstance().getToken() != null && !AppData.getInstance().getToken().isEmpty()) {
                    request = request.newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("token", AppData.getInstance().getToken())
                            .build();
                }
                return chain.proceed(request);
            })
            .addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Info.webserver_url_V2)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(client)
            .build();
}
```

`APIInterface interface`

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(Info.req_v2_search)
Observable<Response<String>> search(@FieldMap Map<String, String> fields);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(Info.req_v2_search)
Observable<Response<String>> search(@Body String body);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(Info.req_v2_search)
Observable<Response<String>> search(@Body RequestBody requestBody);
```

`Presenter class`

```
    // solution 1 : using FieldMap
    @FieldMap Map<String, String> fields; // Injest
    // solution 2 : MultipartBody
    MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
    builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
    for (String key : fields.keySet()) {
        builder.addFormDataPart(key, Objects.requireNonNull(fields.get(key)));
    }
    MultipartBody multipartBody = builder.build();
    // solution 3 : RequestBody and Json string
    JsonObject sendJsonObject = new JsonObject();
    for (String key : fields.keySet()) {
        sendJsonObject.addProperty(key, Objects.requireNonNull(fields.get(key)));
    }
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), sendJsonObject.toString());
```

***but not worked***

and postman outputs `cUrl code` in below works correctly:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://caltech.cntxts.com/v2/search' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cookie: session=FfFHW9bWbcBQ1W0eoV3KTg.J4vQaa4pQdgIzoIRcyCXJuFHVSpXaLvn-8W-ViWugNXmWGt66aTBj3zu8QzrZ9coLnDKCNYRpQNz49WqyuOY5kAEYzuTmO85dKYXPbeS3-Q.1586289772575.31536000000.3PFNma6gTSQ63X-6MJweuJXctYvGLf8_-3Qbj8z8S5E' \
--data-urlencode 'type=product' \
--data-urlencode 'viewMode=0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the request like this, add this in the API interface class:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("{endpoint}")
Observable<Response<String>> hitAPI(@Body JsonObject object);
```

Add the header to it and remove this `.addHeader("Content-Type", " application/json")` from your header and add it individually to each request in the API interface class according to the required type.

Comment: thank you, after some changes on the server side it works fine

Answer (score 2):

You are adding `Content-Type", " application/json` in headers in your [interceptor](https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/) which will rewrite the requests so just remove

```
.addHeader("Content-Type", " application/json")
```

as

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cookieJar(ApiClientCookieJar.getInstance())
            .connectTimeout(Info.connectTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(Info.readTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(Info.writeTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(chain -> {
                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
//                      .addHeader("Content-Type", " application/json") //remove 
                        .build();
                if (AppData.getInstance().getToken() != null && !AppData.getInstance().getToken().isEmpty()) {
                    request = request.newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("token", AppData.getInstance().getToken())
                            .build();
                }
                return chain.proceed(request);
            })
            .addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();
```